# Index of Child XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

Given an `XElement` is there a way to find out that element's index within the parent container?

I know there must be but I just can't figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: The main problem was that the XPath query was modifying the XML document structure...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `e.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count()`

Comment: I'm using `XPathGetElement` which I think is modifying the structure of the document as part of the query so this is always returning zero. Any ideas?

Comment: If `e.Parent` is valid, you could try `e.Parent.Elements().TakeWhile(x => x != e).Count()`.

Comment: This (the original solution in the answer) works perfectly if I replace my XPathGetElement call with an equivalent Linq To XML statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.ToList().IndexOf()` which returns the index of the object you pass in. Example:

```
var index = document.Elements().ToList().IndexOf(element);
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB

```
Dim Index As String = i.ToString.IndexOf(i.ToString)
```